# Cannot access androidx.lifecycle.HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory - Library Module Warning

Tags: android, android-studio, module, android-viewmodel

[image: Android Studio Warning]

Getting -> ***Cannot access androidx.lifecycle.HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory*** Warning On Library Module Activity Class.

Gradle Dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    // debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.2'

    implementation "com.airbnb.android:epoxy:$rootProject.epoxyVersion"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:epoxy-databinding:$rootProject.epoxyVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.airbnb.android:epoxy-processor:$rootProject.epoxyVersion"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"
    implementation "se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:$rootProject.StickyScrollViewItemsVersion"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.constrainlayout_version"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:$rootProject.firebase_core_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$rootProject.firebase_messaging_version"
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$rootProject.crashlytics_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:$rootProject.firebase_core_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$rootProject.firebase_config"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gson_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$rootProject.okhttp_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.retrofit_converter_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$rootProject.retrofit_converter_version"

    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.okhttp_version"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$rootProject.retrofit_version"

    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$rootProject.butterknife_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$rootProject.butterknife_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$rootProject.card_view_version"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$rootProject.legacy_support_version"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$rootProject.recyclerview_version"
    implementation "com.android.volley:volley:$rootProject.volley_version"

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$rootProject.glide_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$rootProject.glide_version"
    implementation "com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:$rootProject.facebook_shimmer_version"
    implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:$rootProject.grid_layout_version"
    implementation "com.github.badoualy:stepper-indicator:$rootProject.stepper_indicator"
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:$rootProject.browser_version"

    implementation "com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:$rootProject.touch_imageview_version"
    implementation "com.orhanobut:logger:$rootProject.orhanobut_logger"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$rootProject.multidex_version"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.dagger2Version"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "com.ethanhua:skeleton:$rootProject.skeleton_version"
    implementation "io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:$rootProject.shimmerlayout_version"

    implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:$rootProject.smack_version"
    implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:$rootProject.smack_version"
    implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:$rootProject.smack_version"
    implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:$rootProject.smack_version"
    implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:$rootProject.smack_version"

    implementation "com.vanniktech:emoji:$rootProject.emoji_version"
    implementation "com.vanniktech:emoji-google:$rootProject.emoji_version"
    implementation "com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:$rootProject.text_drawable_version"

    implementation "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:$rootProject.circle_image_view_version"

    implementation "org.jsoup:jsoup:$rootProject.jsoup_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$rootProject.picasso_version"


    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.room_version"

    // optional - RxJava support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$rootProject.room_version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rx_android_version"

    // Test helpers
    implementation "com.github.smart-fun:XmlToJson:$rootProject.xml_to_json_version"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$rootProject.navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$rootProject.navigation_version"
    implementation "net.opacapp:multiline-collapsingtoolbar:$rootProject.collapsing_toolbar_version"
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:$rootProject.viewpager2_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.material_version"
    implementation "androidx.transition:transition:$rootProject.transition_version"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$rootProject.paging_version"

    implementation project(":evalyPaymentLibrary")
    implementation project(path: ':richlinkpreview')

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    }

}
```

**Versions**

```
ext{
    dagger2Version = '2.16'
    lifecycleVersion = '2.2.0'
    epoxyVersion = '3.9.0'
    appCompatVersion = '1.1.0'
    xml_to_json_version  = '1.4.5'
    room_version  = '2.2.5'
    rx_android_version  = '2.1.1'
    circle_image_view_version = '3.1.0'
    emoji_version = '0.6.0'
    smack_version = '4.3.0'
    shimmerlayout_version = '2.1.0'
    skeleton_version = '1.1.2'
    multidex_version = '2.0.1'
    gson_version  = '2.8.6'
    logger_version = '2.2.0'
    touch_imageview_version = '2.2.0'
    facebook_core_version = '5.0.0'
    finestwebview_version = '1.2.7'
    stepper_indicator = '1.0.7'
    android_support_version = '28.0.0'
    facebook_shimmer_version = '0.5.0'
    glide_version = '4.11.0'
    volley_version = '1.1.1'
    espresso_core_version = '3.0.2'
    runner_version = '1.0.2'
    butterknife_version = '8.1.0'
    loggin_interceptor_version = '3.10.0'
    retrofit_converter_version = '2.7.1'
    okhttp_version = '4.4.0'
    retrofit_version = '2.7.1'
    crashlytics_version = '2.10.1'
    firebase_messaging_version = '20.1.7'
    firebase_core_version  = '17.4.4'
    firebase_config = '19.1.4'
    constrainlayout_version = '1.1.3'
    StickyScrollViewItemsVersion = '1.0.0'
    card_view_version = '1.0.0'
    legacy_support_version = '1.0.0'
    recyclerview_version = '1.1.0'
    grid_layout_version = '1.0.0'
    browser_version = '1.0.0'
    orhanobut_logger = '2.2.0'
    text_drawable_version = '1.0.1'
    jsoup_version = '1.11.3'
    picasso_version = '2.71828'
    navigation_version = '2.3.0'
    collapsing_toolbar_version = '27.1.1'
    viewpager2_version = '1.0.0'
    material_version = '1.3.0-alpha01'
    transition_version = '1.3.1'
    paging_version = '2.1.2'

}
```

Tried **Invalidates Caches** Android Studio Multiple Time. No Good Luck.
My project is running up-to-date, I am using Android Studio 4.0.

**My Project Structure is As Default ->**

```
 my_project 
  -app
  -myLibrary
  -anotherLibrary
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0` dependency

Comment: @DEVV911  - worked well after adding it to library dependency.  Although i am not using viewmodel for my library module. Any explanation for this solution. Thanks